# when saving a post, is there any way to determinate which category belongs to in wordpress and save/not save it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that trigges everytime a post is saved, it works fine, the problem is that I dont know how to get the categories of that post when I save it.

What I want to do is to know the categories and if is from certain category I will save it or not, any idea how to do this?

I have the function for `add_action( 'save_post_product', 'save_product_meta' );`

and inside the save_product_meta im making everything...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) and pass the post object or ID:

```
if( has_term( 'jazz', 'category', $post ) ) {
    // do something
}
```